# Local branch diverged from Origin branch but I do not want to merge/fastforward

Tags: git

Several commits have been pushed to the origin branch. These commits contain code that caused a problem. In order to fix the problem I did a `git reset --hard <sha>` to the commit before the problem started.

I have since fixed the problem and committed locally. Now I want to push to Origin but I cannot because my branch is behind Origin by 5 commits (that caused the problem) and ahead by 1 commit (the fixing commit). ie. diverged branches.

I do not want to merge in any of the changes from Origin. How can I set the head of Origin to that of my Local commit and without merging in the breaking commits into my Local branch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clean way (that preserves history)

1. create a local bugfix branch at your current commit
2. checkout master (or whatever the origin is) and pull it fast-forward to the broken remote HEAD
3. `git revert` the bad commits (everything between the last good *sha* where you forked, and the remote HEAD) ... this removes the unwanted changes while preserving all the history
4. merge your bugfix branch onto master: now all master's changes have been reverted, this will be an easy merge

The dirty way (discards history, discombobulates anyone else working on the remote branch)

1. just use `git push -f` (double-check you have the right options & refspec) and hope no-one else has had their remote branch history change underneath them

Comment: Thanks! 'git push -f ' has done the trick. I caused the break and applied the fix (now) so didn't need to keep the breaking changes. Out of interest what would be the problem if anyone else had their remote branch history change underneath them?

Comment: _they_ wouldn't be able to push any more, because their HEAD is no longer related to the remote HEAD (neither is an ancestor of the other, although they share a common ancestor at your last good _sha_). Their best bet would be to rebase or cherry-pick their changes onto the new remote branch.

Comment: You usually avoid `git push -f` for the same reason you would never rebase already published commits. If anyone had the old version, their repository gets in a state that requires manual fixing to get back to a state where they can interact with the others.

Comment: I thought rebase might come into play but I wasn't sure how it works with remote branches. Thanks both for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want to throw away what others did in those bad commits, i.e. for keeping the history still there, but just to refuse the changes that happened there, you can use the `ours` merge strategy:

```
git merge -s ours badbranch
```

This essentially creates a merge commit that just takes all changes from the current branch and. It will completely ignore what happened on `badbranch` but will still incorporate those in the history. So you can look up the changes that happened there, but they didn’t affect your current version.

Otherwise, if you just want to throw them away completely, and if you have full control over the repository and don’t care about others that pull from your repository, you could overwrite the branch, essentially removing those commits from the repository (unless you have another branch pointing to it). You do that by forcing the push:

```
git push origin master -f
```

Note that this will create conflicts for everyone else working on the repository who might have fetched those changes already, so don’t do that, unless you are really aware of it. It is generally preferred to keep bad commits in the history.