# Completely overwrite a remote branch by the content of a local branch

Tags: git

I made a mistake when using git:

```
#In master, which has commits like a-b-c#
git push origin master
git checkout -b branch2
# Now I'm in the branch2, and I did:
git reset --hard a
# work...
git commit ...
# work...
git commit ...
# so, now I have commits in branch2: a-d-e
```

If I go back to master and merge branch2, it will be something like a-b-c-d-e. However, any thing in commits `b` and `c` are completely garbage that I don't want.

How can I make remote repo to be `a-d-e`? (The remote's master already has `a-b-c` since I did a push before branching to branch2) I really don't want to mess up the repo, will `git push origin master --force` be a good option?

Edit: After goolging `git revert`, I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/git-revert-to-previous-commit-how) worth reading

Comment: It depends on whether anyone else may have seen the remote branch. See, for example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13073230/212858).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git push origin master --force` would rewrite the history as you intend.  However, if there are other developers pulling from the repo it will cause them trouble.

As a rule if you have pushed the commits rather than rewriting history you should do `git revert <sha>` This will make a new commit reversing the changes of the sha provided.  This doesn't erase the problem from the history, but will cause the least amount of trouble.

Comment: You made my day!!! `revert` is EXACTLY what I want! I hope I can upvote you twice, then accept your answer twice